Android as Microphone for Ubuntu without sudo
Is it possible to use an Android phone as microphone on Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop, if I only have sudo access for apk ?
I tried a headset, the quality was low. Is there chance to get better quality with cell phone?

Use droidcam https://droidcam.app/
